# How to check and encode input emojis from Facebook messenger?

Tags: python, facebook, encoding, emoji

I'm building a Facebook messenger bot in Python. And everything works fine. But if I send `emojis` as text from Facebook chat to API, then it goes wrong. 
This is an example when I send `emojis` from Facebook.

```
{'message': {'mid': 'mid.1475846223244:e7eea53884', 'seq': 10863, 'text': ''},
```

So the `received_message = message['message']['text']`. 
What I want is whenever I send a (emoji) `non text message` from Facebook, I can scan and encode it before I send it to my API. I have read documents before asking this question but most of them are given `emojis` from user and not all a scanner and encode any `emojis` (if I miss something, please correct me because i'm a newbie). Tell me if I need to update my question.

Comment: Can you post a `repl` of your 'text' value, or give unicode code-point?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand clearly your question? 'text' value is whatever I send from Facebook and I want to encode it to unicode if 'text' isn't a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a mapping between unicode code-points and ASCII representation. See this kind of table here: http://lolhug.com/facebook-emoticons/

The official Emoticons table is here: http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/

The library [Emoji](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji) can help you to convert your Emojis.

Comment: Thank you for useful information! I will try it now!

Comment: This will not probably allow you to express all the available Unicode code points such as all the emojis.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the escaped version of the corresponding code point. This is a technique that allow you to express the whole Unicode range using only ASCII characters.

EG. The Emoji  can be represented in Java as `"\uD83D\uDCA9"` or in Python as `u"\U0001F4A9"`. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm

NB: some emojis are composed by multiple code points such as flags or families. Please find here the complete list of Unicode Emojis http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html